# SiftGPU and opencv::FundamentalMat

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

I'm trying to use `cv::FindFundamentalMat` but when I try to get the 4th argument (that should be :

> Output array of N elements, every element of which is set to 0 for outliers and to 1 for the other points. The array is computed only in the RANSAC and LMedS methods. For other methods, it is set to all 1’s.
>   )

It only gives me 0's.
I'm using siftGPU to generate the keypoints (x,y) that are used in the function.

My code :

```
/*
... Use siftgpu 
*/
std::vector<int(*)[2]> match_bufs; //Contain (x,y) from the 2 images that are paired
SiftGPU::SiftKeypoint & key1 = keys[match_bufs[i][0]];
SiftGPU::SiftKeypoint & key2 = keys[match_bufs[i][1]];


float x_l, y_l, x_r, y_r; //(x,y of left and right images)
x_l = key1.x; y_l = key1.y;
x_r = key2.x; y_r = key2.y;

vec1.push_back(x_l); vec1.push_back(y_l);
vec2.push_back(x_r); vec2.push_back(y_r); 
std::vector<uchar> results;
int size = vec1.size();
results.resize(size);

std::vector<cv::Point2f> points1;
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points2;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i+=2) {
    points1.push_back(cv::Point2f(vec1[i], vec1[i + 1]));
    points2.push_back(cv::Point2f(vec2[i], vec2[i + 1]));
}

cv::Mat fund = cv::findFundamentalMat(points1, points2, CV_FM_RANSAC, 3, 0.99, results);
```

then,

```
std::cout << std::endl << fund << std::endl;
for (int j = 0; j < results.size(); ++j) {
    std::cout << (int)results[j];
}
```

fund is :

```
   0, -0.001,  0.6
   0,      0, -0.3
-0.4,    0.2,    0
```

and results is composed with only 0's.

I'm maybe fooling myself because findFundamentalMat says :

> Array of N points from the first image. The point coordinates should be floating-point (single or double precision).

Since i'm not native speaker english, there is maybe something that I'm missing... My (x,y) are like (350.0, 560.0) (that are floating points). But do I have to normalize them between [0,1] and that's what floating-point means?

Or do I am missing something else?

Thanks!

(**EDIT** : I tried to normalize my points (divide by height and width of respective images, but results are still 0's)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite easy : I have to use the good format for the template and cast it well. 
So : 
        `((int)results.at<uchar>(i, 0) == 1)`
works :)

If it can help someone.